# How do I pick up RSS URLs using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, rss

Example code:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Fit Living Lifestyle &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.fitlivinglifestyle.com/feed/" />
```

How do I have XPATH check for `type="application/rss+xml"` and if it is present then return me the URL: `http://www.fitlivinglifestyle.com/comments/feed/` (and even the title attribute too)

I have tried some variations of this:

```
//@href[parent::link[contains(@type='application/rss+xml',//@href)]]
```

But don't seem to be quite there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath you are looking for is:

```
link[@type="application/rss+xml"]/@href
```

This selects all `link` elements with `type="application/rss+xml"` and returns the `href` attribute. To return the `title` attribute use:

```
link[@type="application/rss+xml"]/@title
```

Comment: That works thanks. Wondered how I could refine the results to I only return a URL if it looks like this: http://www.fitlivinglifestyle.com/feed/, as at the moment some pages have 3 URLs with stuff like http://www.fitlivinglifestyle.com/comments/feed/ too.

Comment: Probably not the most elegant solution out there, but this works: `link[@type="application/rss+xml" and @href="http://www.fitlivinglifestyle.com/feed"]/@href`

Comment: Yes, but I won't know the name of the root website I am looking at of course, this will run on 100 unknown URLs, so I cannot specify the URL (fitliving).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with the exact URLs you are looking for? There may be a solution using XPath, but it might be easier to select all of the URLs using XPath and then use regex to narrow down your search

Comment: I want only the URL that follows this format 'http://www.example.com/feed' I am looking for RSS feed URLs, not comments or posts, so only a URL that follows that exact structure. ''example.com/FEED'

Comment: If you are using XPath 2.0 you can use the `ends-with` function: `link[@type="application/rss+xml" and ends-with(@href, "feed")]/@href`. If you are using XPath 1.0 then you can use the `contains` function to see if "feed" is a substring of the `@href` value: `link[@type="application/rss+xml" and contains(@href, "feed")]/@href`

Comment: Ok, this one will do it: //link[@type="application/rss+xml" and contains(@href, ".com/feed")]/@href

Comment: Great - your solution is a bit more exact than mine, but I think I put you on the right track!

Comment: Of course, I won't be taking the credit. Also, this isn't perfect as not all websites are ".com"